# How echo a variable that contains html, from another script?

Tags: php, html

I have a php script which contains few variables e.ct "welcome.php"

```
<?php
  $hello = '<p class="fontBlack15">we will collect your rent to co-inside with your student loan payments. </p>';
?>
```

In another php script "hello.php" i have:

```
<?php include 'welcome.php';?>

<div id="header"><? echo $hello; ?></div>
```

This doenst work... and i dont really know much why?

Thank you

Comment: What is happening when you run your script?

Comment: you are working on localhost or at server??

Comment: Are you get error? put that.

Comment: ***<?php*** please not **<?**

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should change

`<div id="header"><? echo $hello; ?></div>`

into

`<div id="header"><?php echo $hello; ?></div>`

or change `short_open_tag` to `1`

**EDIT**

Or if you use PHP 5.4+ you can also simple use:

`<div id="header"><?= $hello; ?></div>`

to display variable's value regardless of `short_open_tag` settings

Answer (score 2):

This is because XAMPP doesn't allow using the short version of PHP syntax.

```
<div id="header"><?php echo $hello; ?></div>
```

You must use `<?php` instead of  `<?`

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your short tags are working.
else go to php.ini file and uncomment short_open_tag

Answer (score 0):

Though you did not specify whether your files are in same directory or not? If the answer by **Ozan Kurt** and **Marcin Nabiałek** didn't workout for you, then may be your files are in a different directories and for that you have to give directory path in your include e.g.

```
<?php include '../your_file_path/welcome.php'; ?> 

then

<div id="header"><?php echo $hello; ?></div>
```